# How does the primitive streak disappear after gastrulation?

Tags: development, embryology

So, I am not a biologist or anything related to the field, but this question is indirectly related to something I am curious about. 
I read some articles about the role of the primitive streak in the development of the human embryo. And it says in some of them that after gastrulation, the primitive streak regress caudally or disappears. So, my question is how does it disappear, what happens to the cells that constitute it? 
And this might be a little strange, but does it have anything to do with the formation of the coccyx?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology! It can help to take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't already. It would help to see direct quotes from the articles you refer to and any links/references to such articles. Have you tried e.g. a google search, and if so, what did you find? e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_streak) notes that the primitive streak becomes the mesoderm, the germ layer that gives rise to all bones (including the coccyx).

Comment: I am sorry, but I have read the wikipedia page before and I think it doesn't mention that the primitive streak transforms into the mesoderm. It says that after gastrulation, it regresses (which i don't understand where the cells that disappeared have gone) and by day 20, the remaining cells constitute a midline caudal cell mass (which i don't understand what it means either). And by day 26, it has seemingly disappeared(didn't explain how did it disappear). Please if I am missing something point it to me, as I am not a professional.

Comment: Fair enough- I did not read closely, and it is not as specific as what I said. Nonetheless, it would be helpful for you to excerpt the relevant sections in your question and explain what you don't understand. I would still suggest further research, for example when I google "primitive streak cell fate" I found articles like [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0925477395004939) that have a fate map for the primitive streak.

Comment: My shot in dark (read the Wiki article): The *linea primitiva* establishes 1)bilateral symmetry and 2) craniocaudal axis and 3)germ layer formation (gastrulation). I suppose it serves as some kind anatomicochemical landmark which embryonic cells recognize and serves as a cue as to 1. what they should do and 2. where they should do it. Once this function is served, the *linea primitiva* "disappears". The only features in an adult human that corresponds to the *linea primitiva* are the *vertebral column* (structure) and the *spinal cord* (central nervous system).